# Calculation of a double integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Can you help me to calculate this integral.  $$\begin{align}I&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{1+xy}\right)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ln(x+1)}{x(x^2+1)}dx\\
&=\ldots\end{align}$$
Its clear that this integral is integrable. Is there some specific technique to make the calculation?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Let you know that $\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\arctan(x)+c.$

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis we all know it. Thank you anyway

Comment: I think that the answer can be obtained by a series expansion.

Comment: @Did: No, that is for $\log{(1+x^2)}$, not $\log{(1+x)}$.  I made the same mistake below.

Comment: @RonGordon Note that $$\frac1{1+x^2}\frac1{1+xy}=\frac1{1+x^2}\frac1{1+y^2}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\frac{y}{1+y^2}+\frac{y}{1+y^2}\frac{y}{1+xy}$$ hence $I=J^2-K^2+L$ with $$J=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}4,\quad K=\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\ln2}2,$$ and $$L=\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\left(\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+xy}dx\right) dy=\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+y^2}\ln(1+y)dy.$$ Now, $$I=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\ln(1+x)dx,$$ hence $$I+L=\int_0^1\frac1x\ln(1+x)dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^{n-1}}ndx=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac1{n^2}=\frac12\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^2},$$ ...

Comment: ...  that is, $$I+L=\frac{\pi^2}{12},$$ and finally, $$I=\frac{7\pi^2}{96}-\frac{(\ln2)^2}8,$$ modulo the typos you will soon find in all this. :-)

Comment: @Did: brilliant - I was working the single integral which was requiring some imaginative integrations by parts, and, long story short...your way is better.  Then again, not better than this: "Hint: Take the Mellin transform and let $s \to 0$."

Comment: @RonGordon Thanks. Would you explain the Mellin thing?

Comment: @Did: I was making fun of bad hints.  (And when one has to explain a joke, the joke is by definition bad.)

Comment: @RonGordon No, no, my fault (I happen to be rather tired at the moment, irl...).